# Problems with the UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm building a little app where I show in a TableView an array. The problem is that I don't want to use  a UITableViewController, I just wanna use a ViewController. When I run the app in the simulator, it doesn't show the array. Here's the code:

```
.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UITableView *table;
    NSArray *array;
}

.m


  - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    array  =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"iPad",@"iTV" ,nil];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

        return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

        return [array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Please don't answer this saying that I have to use a UITableViewController. I know is possible to manage this without it, just using a ViewController. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your interface like

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    IBOutlet UITableView *table;
    NSArray *array;
}
```

and set `table`'s `delegate` and `dataSource` outlet to `File's owner`, and `File's owner`'s class as `ViewController` in xib.

First browse in your project, click the xib file for your view controller. Then select the table view from the list of objects. In this case, there may be some extra consideration:

If you have already created the xib with UITableViewController, you need to modify it to fit for UIViewController. Remember, the UIViewController subclass instance is shown as File's owner object. You need to make sure that there is a top-level UIView object, which is not added as subview of any other view, and that there is a UITableView in the UIView.

[image: Referencing outlets]

The UIView should have a referencing outlet: view - File's owner. If not, drag from the white circle of `New Referencing Outlet` to `File's Owner`, release mouse and then click on `view`.

For the table view, click and drag from `New Referencing Outlet`, and drop to File's Owner, and click `table`, and drag from `dataSource`, `delegate`, and drop to File's Owner, respectively.

BTW, it is recommended to use some capital characters as prefix for any class name.

Comment: So... I thought that it was already done but it isn't yet. I don't know how to do what are you saying about to connect the delegate and the dataSource with the File's owner, please if u could explain this part I will be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You must follow the TableViewDelegate Protocol...[http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html]